# When does fwprintf return a negative number?

Tags: c, widechar

I couldn't find it in the docs anywhere, all I did find was that it returns a negative number when an error occurs. What error can it be?

The error occurs in a function that looks like this:

```
void foo(wchar_t** a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (fwprintf(stderr, L"%ls ", a[i]) < 0)
            puts("OOPS!");
    fwprintf(stderr, L"\n");
}
```

Also, this error appears only at one point during the program execution and stays there, as if some kind of limit was reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definition of [fwprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fwprintf/?kw=fwprintf):

> Return Value
> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.
>
> If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned.
>
> If a multibyte character encoding error occurs while writing wide characters, errno is set to EILSEQ and a negative number is returned.

So it is either returning a negative number because of a writing error or a multibyte character encoding error. Since you are using a wide char double pointer it is most likely the latter, so check the `errno` to see if it is set to `EILSEQ`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the failure reasons for [`fwprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fwprintf.html) are mostly the same with that of [`fputwc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fputwc.html). You can always check the `errno` go get the exact nature of errors.

To quote the man page, type of the errors are,

> [EAGAIN]
>
> [EBADF]
>
> [EFBIG]
>
> [EFBIG]
>
> [EINTR]
>
> [EIO]
>
> [ENOSPC]
>
> [EPIPE]
>
> [ENOMEM]
>
> [ENXIO]
>
> [EILSEQ]
>
> [EINVAL]